# Wordpress doesnt show full page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a problem it doesnt show fullwidth can u please check it here in the link

[Click Here for the web](http://www.zwickypartner.ch/?page_id=1431)

I have tried to remove the white space with this code but it shows again

```
wrapper {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that outlines the issue you're experiencing (preferably with citations of previous research you've done, and a clearer explanation of what, *specifically*, is incorrect/undesired).  As @Adam mentioned, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: yess u can check the link and u would see the white space @ footer.
i will add ur code and see it fix my problem or not . check out the link and u will understand whats my problem

Answer (score 0):

Very very very very very unclear but i get what you want.

You do not want fullwidth, because it's already the case, but fullheight to remove the bottom white space.
`display: none;` won't do that. It will ... **not display** your wrapper at all.

Someone in the comments said to set #wrapper height to 100vh but it's not recommanded because, maybe one day your content will be higher than that so set `min-height: 100vh;` instead.

Also to target your wrapper that has an **ID** you must add **"#"** before its name. 
If it was a **class**, you would need to target it with a **"."** before its name.

So :

```
#wrapper {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

If its not working because of plugins or theme or anything, try to add !important after "100vh" and before ";".

**You do not seem to know the css well, so you should try to find tutorials on the internet to get the basics. This is not so difficult and it would help you a lot.**